# Get all .m4a files in JS

Tags: javascript, regex

```
var pattern = new RegExp(".m4a$");
    if (msg.text.toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(jazz) === 0) {
        let file = __dirname + `/pattern`;
    }
```

This code with regexp is supposed to get all files in root having m4a format. But this never happens. How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

https://www.npmjs.com/package/select-random-file

One should study this npm packet